# React how to inline style different objects in one element

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In React i'm trying to apply style only to one object inside of an element like h1 here is an example

```
const Header = () => {

  const firstName = "Ashraf";
  const lastName = "Fathi";
  const date = new Date();
  const hours = date.getHours();

  let timeOfDay;
  const styles = {
    color: ""
  }
  if (hours < 12) {
    timeOfDay = "Good morning"
    styles.color = "#ff474d"
  }
  else if (hours >= 12 && hours < 17) {
    timeOfDay = "Good afternoon"
    styles.color = "#7b5dff"
  }
  else {
    timeOfDay = "Good night"
    styles.color = "#01ff41"
  }
  return(
    <div>
          <h1 className="navbar" style={styles}>{timeOfDay} {`${firstName} ${lastName}`} It is currently {hours} clock</h1>
    </div>
    )
}
```

what i'm trying to do is to apply style to only timeOfDay so how could i achieve that? i have tried different approaches but it all comes down to style={} affecting the whole element which is not looking for. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `span` around `timeOfDay` and then pass style to it

```
 <div>
      <h1 className="navbar"><span style={styles}>{timeOfDay}</span> {`${firstName} ${lastName}`} It is currently {hours} clock</h1>
</div>
```